# Clone objects using Serialization by byte array java

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization, clone, bytearrayinputstream

How to serialize and deserialize objects using ByteArrayOutputStream and  ByteArrayInputStream?
I need a simple and explicit explanation of this topic.

It's a template of this method:

```
public class Cloner {

    public <T> T clone(T value) { … }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do just what you said:

1. Create a `ByteArrayOutputStream`
2. Serialize it to that `ByteArrayOutputStream`, via `new ObjectOutputStream(baos)`
3. Get the byte array out of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`
4. Wrap a `ByteArrayInputStream` around it
5. Wrap an `ObjectInputStream` around that
6. De-serialize.

NB your generic signature could usefully be `<T extends Serializable>`.